# Dynamics CRM 8.2 - Outlook 365 - Hyperlink not recognized

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, office365

When clicking on "Email a link" from a Dynamics CRM form, Outlook opens with the link, but this link is not recognized as hyperlink, so not clickable.

Did you also experience this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When I click "Email a Link" it does open my outlook and gives result as below

```
Account Name

<https://crm.abc.com/Dev/main.aspx?etc=1&extraqs=formid%3d11933125-02ea-4830-90cd-4ba00df70b6a&id=%7bB6B35FD0-B9C3-E311-88E2-00505693000C%7d&pagetype=entityrecord>
```

Which is the expected and correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click the hyperlink when the Outlook email is in Draft mode.

You can change this settings if you want.

`Outlook -> File -> Options -> Mail -> Editor Options -> Advanced`

[image]